# Dont open second activity if android back button is pressed

Tags: android

i am trying to implement below code every thing works fine how ever 
here is the situation i am facing

1. mainactivity just has a button to open splashactivity
2. splash activity does the parsing part then opens the listactvity
3. my workflow is if user has clicked on the button in main activity
   it opens the splash activity and redirects to listactivty the
   problem occurs when on the splash activity if a user clicks the
   andorid back button it does go back to the mainactivity however the
   parsing in splashactivity continues and user is redirected to
   listactivty this thing should not happen, when user on splash
   activity has clicked backbutton it should go back to mainactivity
   and stay there itself

how can this be done

```
package com.site.name;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {


    RSSFeed feed;
    String fileName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        fileName = "TDRSSFeed.td";
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position =  i.getExtras().getInt("position");
        String[] country = i.getStringArrayExtra("country");
//      //public String RSSFEEDURL = "http://blogname.blogspot.com//feeds/posts/default/-/Awards?alt=rss";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File feedFile = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {

            // No connectivity. Check if feed File exists
            if (!feedFile.exists()) {

                // No connectivity & Feed file doesn't exist: Show alert to exit
                // & check for connectivity
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(
                        "Unable to reach server, \nPlease check your connectivity.")
                        .setTitle("TD RSS Reader")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Exit",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {

                // No connectivty and file exists: Read feed from the File
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                        "No connectivity!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                //feed = ReadFeed(fileName);
                startLisActivity(feed);
            }

        } else {

            // Connected - Start parsing
            new AsyncLoadXMLFeed().execute();

        }

    }

    private void startLisActivity(RSSFeed feed) {


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);

                // launch List activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                    // kill this activity
                    finish();

    }

    private class AsyncLoadXMLFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Obtain feed
            DOMParser myParser = new DOMParser();
            Intent i = getIntent();
            int position =  i.getExtras().getInt("position");
            String[] country = i.getStringArrayExtra("country");
            //feed = myParser.parseXml(RSSFEEDURL);
            //feed = myParser.parseXml("http://blogname.blogspot.com//feeds/posts/default/-/Awards?alt=rss");
            feed = myParser.parseXml("http://blogname.blogspot.com//feeds/posts/default/-/" + country[position] + "?alt=rss");
            if (feed != null && feed.getItemCount() > 0)
                WriteFeed(feed);
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            startLisActivity(feed);
        }

    }

    // Method to write the feed to the File
    private void WriteFeed(RSSFeed data) {

        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        ObjectOutputStream osw = null;

        try {
            fOut = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            osw = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
            osw.writeObject(data);
            osw.flush();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //Include the code here
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: explain you activity flow clearly

Comment: you are very unclear about what you are asking.. please improve your question so we can understand and give you solution

Comment: i just want to check if back button is clicked in splash activity and then stop parsing there itself and not go to  the listactivity, which happens even if i have pressed the backbutton in splash activity

Comment: dude, are you trying to confuse us ? :D , please edit your question be clear, and kindly illustrate your activity flow in points.

Comment: 1) main activity just has a button to open splashactivity

Comment: 1)mainactivity just has a button to open splashactivity 2)splash activity does  the parsing part then opens the listactvity 3)my workflow is if user has  clicked on the button in main activity it opens the splash activity and redirects to listactivty the problem occurs when on the splash activity if a user clicks the andorid back button it does go back to the mainactivity however the parsing in splashactivity continues and user is redirected to listactivty this thing should not happen, when user on splash activity has clicked backbutton it should go back to mainactivity and stay there itself

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel parsing the feed in MainActivity's onRestart() as this is one method of MainActivity that will be called when you press back from your Parsing Activity.

You can read more about Activity Life Cycle [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the Back button press event use the following method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // do something on back.
   // Change your activity by calling intent
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do anything with your back button then you have to override it manually.

```
@Override
Public void onBackPressed() {

//do whatever you want to do as your question is quite confusing.    

return;
}
```